# C# Project is not loaded - error : The element <#text> beneath element <Target>

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a .Net project that till today was loading without any problem.
Suddenly , without any change , I got the following error while opening visual studio and trying to load the project:

> error  : The element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized.
>   C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

When I removed from the .csproj the following line the project have bean loaded

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

But I can't compile the project...

Someone can assist?

Thanks!

Comment: That line you removed, can you show it with surrounding text from the csproj file?

Comment: Also, can you find (and inspect/show) that Microsoft.CSharp.targets file?

Comment: No, it was with tags , but I removed it since stackoverflow didn't show it. about your 2nd question , I opened it and I checked and see that it is a valid xml. Thanks!